# WebSphere 7.0 is removing closing tags from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, websphere

I have this problem deploying to WebSphere that it is removing closing tags in a JSP.  It's a well known fact that doing this will cause issues in most browsers and sure enough, it is causing problems during rendering of the JSP.

So, a JSP with this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/calendar.js"></script>`

Is being rendered and sending

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/calendar.js"/>`

this completely ruins the next lines of html until a  is hit but by then it is too late

Is there a way to fix this by not "optimizing" and removing scripts without whitespace?

Update,

adding a black space in the script keeps the closing tag though the space is removed.

So, a JSP with this:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/calendar.js"> </script>`

Is being rendered and sending

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/calendar.js"/></script>`

This is an esoteric working around but not a solution.

Update,

I'm using JSPX (which is new to me and I was intrigued by the pros but have come across far too many cons)

parent JSP

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0"
          xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
          xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
          xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags">

    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true" doctype-root-element="HTML"
            doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>

    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <jsp:include page="/scripts/scripts.jspx"/>

    </head>
</html>
```

child JSP:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1">
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/calendar.js"></script> 

</jsp:root>
```

Comment: I've seen this as well.  Are you using `.jsp` or `.jspx` files?  What is the content-type being rendered?

Comment: We are using .jspx and perhaps more important, including a child JSP.   I have updated with an example

Comment: So...what is your question?

Comment: To have it not remove the end tag, </script>, @AlvinThompson

Comment: Looks like this has been asked before.  It also looks like there's no way to make that happen automatically, because the jspx is an xml document, which should automatically condense the tags when they have no content.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434755/script-tags-not-rendered-in-jsp-page-using-spring-tiles-jspx

Comment: Ah, so this is more of a JSPX problem than WebSphere?  That is strange.. because WebLogic doesn't do this.. :|

Comment: @ThomasBeauvais: I see. From here it looked a lot like you already had a solution to this problem and were just using SO as a forum to whine that the solution was necessary, thereby wasting people's time.