# Why adding <script> tag on jsp causes error?

Tags: javascript, jsp, tags

when i add  tag in **Jsp** ,it causes error ,it shows

multiple annotation found on this line:
- identifier expected
- ';' expected
what happened actually?

```html
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/demo.js"> </script>
```

Comment: avoid putting an image for code, you should instead copy over the code and paste it, putting it into code formate using code brackets (triple backticks)

Comment: I think, is related to: [Script tags not rendered in JSP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434755/script-tags-not-rendered-in-jsp-page-using-spring-tiles-jspx)

Comment: i just deleted the image and added code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply add the semicolon at the end of the line 5?

Comment: i just did,the line become ok but other lines still show error